# Coordinates of the farthest point from centroid

Tags: matlab, image-processing

i have calculated the centroid of the image and now want to know the coordinates of the farthest point on the object boundary from the centroid.

i used following code to calculate the maximum distance.

```
 boundaries = bwboundaries(pad);
thisBoundary = boundaries{1};
boundaryX=thisBoundary(:,1); 
boundaryY=thisBoundary(:,2);
% Get the distances of the boundary pixels from the centroid.
distances= sqrt((boundaryX - a2).^2 + (boundaryY - b2).^2); 
% Scan the boundary to find the pixel on it that is
% farthest from the centroid.
maxRadius = max(distances);
 disp(maxRadius);
```

please if any one know how to calculate the coordinates of the farthest point on the object boundary from the centroid. the distance of the farthest point from the centroid is calculated above as maxRadius. here a2, b2 are the centroid coordinates of the object 'pad'.

Comment: please if any one know what?

Comment: This is not a question...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, you seem to be asking "how do I find which of the input values `max` has chosen as the maximum". You need to use the second output argument of `max`. For your specific case, this gives something like:

```
[maxRadius, maxInd] = max(distances);
maxCoord = thisBoundary(maxInd, :);
```

Please read [the `max` function's documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/max.html). Please also make the exact question you are asking a bit clearer next time.

Comment: thank you! i get the answer of what i asked ... but i realize my logic  went wrong.

Comment: i wanted to calculate the top point of the object. thought that would be the farthest. but it isn't :(